# Gcloud transfer snapshots to nearline storage

Tags: storage, google-cloud-platform, snapshot

I've setup my servers in google cloud to take regular snapshots. This is working fine, but I would like to move the snapshots to nearline storage because there's a big difference in pricing:

- For snapshots storage, price is $0.026/GB/month
- For nearline storage, price is $0.01/GB/month

However I haven't found any way to transfer the snapshots to nearline storage. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly upload [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) to GCS but you can upload [images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) created using standard linux utilities. There is a very similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665352/can-i-download-an-snapshot-in-google-compute-engine).